# How to Properly Display RenderedMarkdownField() on Template when "safe" Isn't "Working"?

Tags: python, django, markdown

On my django website, I'm using a `RenderedMarkdownField()` to make some fancy looking description text on my posts. My model looks like this:

```
# Portfolio project overview model
class Work(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # description = models.TextField()
    description = MarkdownField(rendered_field='description_rendered', validator=VALIDATOR_STANDARD)
    description_rendered = RenderedMarkdownField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="work_app/media/images/", null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="work_app/media/videos/", null=True, blank=True)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to="work_app/media/documents/", null=True, blank=True)
    
    # To show the title in the Admin page
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Then my `work_index.html` page looks like this when rendering each project from my database (personally identifying/crucial info scratched out):

[image: OriginalRender]

As you can see, the Markdown characters in the description text (the *'s) are visible in this description. To fix this, we use Django's `safe` tag and render the `work.description_rendered` field instead, so my code when iterating through each post looks like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        {% for work in works %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-2">
                    <a href="{% url 'work_detail' work.pk %}">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ work.image.url }}">
                    </a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="{% url 'work_detail' work.pk %}">
                            <h5 class="card-title project-title-link">{{ work.title }}</h5>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ work.description_rendered | safe | truncatechars:200 }}</p>
                        <a href="{% url 'work_detail' work.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Read More
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

...HOWEVER, once I make those changes with that `safe` tag added, and change `work.description` to `work.description_rendered` as per django-markdown, my rendered page then gets screwed up and looks like this:

[image: NewRender]

Notice how the "row" now gets changed to a "column" of posts for some reason, as well, the bottom post's description text is all bolded, when that is definitely NOT how I have it in the markdown description. Wondering if someone can tell me what's going on here, or if I need to use a different tag other than `safe`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are rendering the Rendered Markdown into a `<p>` tag which is resulting in invalid HTML. Use a `<div>` instead.

Markdown will wrap the the paragraphs within its content in `<p>` tags. However, the HTML spec does not allow a `<p>` tag to contain another `<p>` tag. Therefore, you should wrap the content in a `<div>` or some other generic block level tag.

```
<div class="card-text">{{ work.description_rendered | safe | truncatechars:200 }}</div>
```

I suggest using your browser's 'inspect' tool to see how the browser is rendering the HTML of the page. That will help when debugging issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however even with wrapping it in a `div` tag instead of a `p` tag, it's still rendering weird. I do see when rendering it in a `div` and NOT using `safe` that the text does get wrapped in a `p` automatically, so that helps, but it's still stacking the entries vertically when I use `safe` and it's bolding the second entry's text still. I do see in the inspect that it's not rendering like how I have it in the `template` file so something's getting changed between the template and the rendered page. I'll keep digging...